# How to block systems bar (or recent app and home soft key) in android 4 or higher?

Tags: android-activity

In my activity,I'd like to lock the screen prevent the user interacting with my app(like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.argotronic.touchblocker&hl=en ) , I have override **dispatchTouchEvent** method,but with the systems (navigator and status) bar i can't do anything, i have searched in google and stackoverflow, but i haven't found the answer :(,

Please help me !!!

Comment: My device must not root :(((